# Relationship between polynomial approximation and power series expansion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We can always find a polynomial of degree n whose graph goes through n points (x,y) in the plane. Given a function on an interval then, we can find a polynomial that closely approximate the function by making it goes through a number of evenly-spaced points given by the function.The more points we want it to go through, the higher the degree that the function needs to be.

I am wondering what is the relation of this fact with the fact that some function can be approximated by its Taylor expansion. As far as I know, a function can only be approximated by its Taylor expansion in an interval where its remainder term(Taylor theorem) goes to 0 as n goes to infinity.

I have a feeling that the two facts above are connected somehow. However, I am left with some questions:

-Why are there intervals where a function cannot be approximated using Taylor theorem(the series diverges) where, theoretically, the polynomial approximation argument can be used for all function and the approximation can be made as accurately as possible by making the distance between the chosen points to be as tight as possible?

-The fact that a Taylor series that converges to a function is unique, while, through n points in a function, you can have infinitely many polynomial of degree n+1 through it.

Can someone give me a reference that shred some light on the relationship between these? Is there any proof of Taylor theorem that uses the idea of polynomial approximation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Taylor polynomial of order $n$ of a function $f$ at a point $a$ is defined if $f$ is $n$ times differentiable on a neighborhood of $a$. It approximates $f(x)$ locally, that is, near $x=a$. For instance, $x-x^3/3$ is a good approximation of $\sin x$ for small $x$, but not for, say, $x\ge1$.

Interpolation by polynomials may be done for continuous functions. However, it is not always true that the sequence of interpolating polynomials on evenly spaced nodes approximates the function ([Runge's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon).)

Finally, you should read about [Weirstrass approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).