# Link between interpolation and numerical series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, fourier-series, interpolation

There are the following types of interpolation:

- polynomial interpolation
- trigonometric interpolation.

There are also the following types of numerical series:

- Taylor series, as a power series
- Fourier series, as a trigonometric series.

It feels like there is a link between the concepts of interpolation and numerical series. Is it just a coincidence, or it is more to say about it? I mean, given a series, can we plug the corresponding basis functions into an interpolation task?

Comment: A limited anwer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPZIo.png
Source: https://www.math.ust.hk/~mamu/courses/231/Slides/CH03_1A.pdf

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301155/relationship-between-polynomial-approximation-and-power-series-expansion